# Lazy-loading React components under SSR

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, server-side-rendering, react-lazy-load

I have a ReactJS app built with `react-lazy-load-image-component` in order to improve performance.

My code wraps components that take time to initialize with something like:

```
<h2 className={styles.sectionTitle}>Categories</h2>
<Row>
  {categories &&
    categories.map((category, index) => {
      if (category.image) {
        return (
          <Col
            xs={6}
            md={4}
            key={index}
            className={[
              'col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3',
              styles.thumbnail
            ].join(' ')}
          >
            <LazyLoadComponent>
              <CategoryButton {...category} />
            </LazyLoadComponent>
          </Col>
        );
      }
      return null;
    })}
</Row>
```

It is working fine. However, this there is the lazy-load, SSR prints my markup as:

```
<h2>Categories</h2>
<div class="row"></div>
```

I want the server to print everything, so crawlers would have an easy time indexing my pages. The library that I am using supports the `visibleByDefault` property, which is probably the way to go.

I am just wondering how to pass it from my loader doing:

```
<Capture report={m => modules.push(m)}>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
      <Frontload isServer={true}>
        <App />
      </Frontload>
    </StaticRouter>
  </Provider>
</Capture>
```

all the way to each `<LazyLoadComponent>`?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended-up doing:

```
import React from 'react';

import { LazyLoadComponent } from 'react-lazy-load-image-component';
import useSSR from 'use-ssr';

const LazyLoad = ({ children }) => {
  var { isServer } = useSSR();
  return (
    <LazyLoadComponent visibleByDefault={isServer}>
      {children}
    </LazyLoadComponent>
  );
};

export default LazyLoad;
```